# CMAKE add_custom_command still confusing

Tags: android, cmake, cmake-custom-command

I reviewed the response for using the add_custom_command for cmake and was not able to get it to work in android studio. I am having trouble finding the target when run.

```
add_custom_command( TARGET b.c.o
                    POST_BUILD
                    file(RENAME ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/customer.txt ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/used_customer.txt)
                  )
```

I get the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (add_custom_command):
  No TARGET ')' has been created in this directory.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Documents/Android_files/local_app/BApp/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':BApp'.
    > executing external native build for cmake C:\Documents\Android_files\local_app\BApp\CMakeLists.txt

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s

It appears to not be able to find the target file each time I run it.
Can you provide some help with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest cmake commands ([file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/file.html?highlight=file) is a cmake command) in add_custom_command. The command from add_custom_command is executed in terminal, not from inside the cmake script.
You can use [mv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) in linux to rename a file:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET b.c.o POST_BUILD COMMAND mv ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/customer.txt ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/used_customer.txt)
```

You can use [rename](https://www.computerhope.com/renamehl.htm) in windows to rename a file:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET b.c.o POST_BUILD COMMAND rename ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/customer.txt ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/used_customer.txt)
```

You can use cmake command mode (probably the best option):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET b.c.o POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rename ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/customer.txt ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/used_customer.txt)
```

Or you can put the cmake command:

```
  file(RENAME ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/customer.txt ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/newfolder/used_customer.txt)
```

in a separate file called `custom_command.cmake` and do:

```
   add_custom_command(TARGET b.c.o POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P custom_command.cmake -D CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY} )
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. I am still having trouble with finding the target. The problem with cmake is that comprehensive documentation does not exist. Or at least I haven't see any. It would be nice to get access to a real user manual. My target is in a cmake object folder but using the path name does not solve the problem. How do I tell cmake how to find the target?

Comment: You can find cmake documentation online [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/add_custom_command.html) (remember to choose correct cmake version up left).

Comment: cmake object folder? You mean CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR? Check out [cmake usefull variables](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables).

Comment: When I run the rename command, it creates a new file rather than overwrite the existing one. I assume this is because the build is not done using the file and blocks deleting the original. If this is the case, how can I tell it to delete after all of the builds are complete?

Comment: POST_BUILD commands are run lastly, after all have been built. Maybe try with `add_dependencies(b.c.o. <build you want to complete before running b.c.o.>)`. To delete the file, you may just add [del](https://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm) a second `COMMAND del <file>` after the first command, or try using [move](https://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) command.